# How to remove big spaces in a bibliographic entry

Tags: bibtex, urls

As you can see in the reference, there are big spaces in the author names as well was in the URL part. This is what I used.

```
@misc{griffith_nowakowski, 
title={Powering Medical Ultrasound Imaging},
url={https://www.mouser.ca/applications/medical-ultrasound-power-supply/}, 
editor={Mouser Electronics Canada - Electronic Components Distributor}, 
author={Griffith, Chris and Nowakowski, Rich}
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: you could use `\raggedright` at the start of the references

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you show me how to do it, coz I have a big .bib file. I try doing it but it doesn't work

Comment: not in the bib file, in your tex file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it aligns everything to the left which I don't want

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the spacing issues are caused by a failure on your part to load a package that knows how to split long URL strings in a flexible manner.

I suggest you load the `xurl` package, which allows line-breaking of long URL strings at arbitrary, i.e., all possible points. If your document happens to load the `hyperref` package as well, be sure to load `xurl` before `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
\@misc{griffith_nowakowski, 
  title={Powering Medical Ultrasound Imaging},
  url={https://www.mouser.ca/applications/medical-ultrasound-power-supply/}, 
  editor={Mouser Electronics Canada--Electronic Components Distributor}, 
  author={Griffith, Chris and Nowakowski, Rich}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % or some other suitable bib style
\usepackage{xurl} % must load 'xurl' before 'hyperref'
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{griffith_nowakowski}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```